# iOS 5 Twitter API bad performance slow

Tags: ios, performance, twitter

it is nice, that apple integrated twitter as a native part of iOS 5. But the performance really sucks. I used to add a loading indicator for any twitter action. The loading time lasts on the iPad 1 over a minute. The iPad 3 is much faster but it is still annoying.

Has anyone experienced the same problem and solved this? Is there any way to preload the hard part of twitter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the code you are using for this, every iOS 5 twitter composer I've used has less than a second of load time.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved this by executing the Twitter requests in a background thread.